# How to obtain different random numbers in the same program

Tags: c++, random, boost

I wrote this :

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::mt19937 rng(time(0)); 
  boost::normal_distribution<> nd(0.0, 1.0);

  boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, 
                       boost::normal_distribution<> > var_nor(rng, nd);
 double d = var_nor();
 }
```

`d` contains the random numbers I want. How should I do if I need more random numbers LIKE THIS ONE in the same program and in the same cicle for example?!  Now I am seeding it with the time of the computer. And I am using the boost library.

Comment: Why do you use boost random library? <random> is valid in C++11, can't you use C++11?

Comment: What do you mean with `numbers LIKE THIS ONE`? What is a cicle?

Comment: Are you asking about creating another rand object with the same seed?

Comment: @UKMonkey yes ,  I need more object like d but with different value

Comment: @xskxzr I need real number with a gaussian distribution with mean 0 and std 1

Comment: @AndreaAngeletti so do exactly the same as you did there; but use a different seed?

Comment: @schorsch312 yes infact I give new values to d at each loop cycle , i need in the same cycle another random number like d but with different value of course

Comment: @UKMonkey yeah you are right , which seed I should use ? this is the point , I know just the one with the time that allows me quite good random numbers which does not repeat on time . thanks

Comment: @AndreaAngeletti You could just add 1 to the previous seed so that you end up with a different seed; thus different random numbers.

Comment: Seed it with the random device, as in the linked question